# Client gets ECONNREFUSED on start up from Server. Client connects after start up

Tags: c++, python-3.x, linux, sockets

Client device is c++ on linux.

Server device is python on windows.

Client issues the the connect(), then select(), then getsockopt() to ensure the connection is valid.

When the client is already running and attempts a connection to the server, it works. Client can send messages and the server outputs the messages.

However, when the client starts up and makes the attempt at the connection to the server it gets 111 ([ECONNREFUSED](https://programmerah.com/linux-getsockopt-so_error-values-errno-h-10319/))

Wireshark shows that communication is working initially but the server simulator does send the TCP [RST, ACK]

```
C -> SYN
S -> SYN, ACK
C -> ACK
C -> FIN, ACK
S -> ACK
S -> FIN, ACK
C -> ACK
C -> SYN
S -> RST, ACK
```

Server simulator code

```
def recv_msgs(self, proto):

    proto.connection.settimeout(5)
    proto.running = True

    while proto.running:
        try:
            msg = proto.connection.recv(proto.MAX_MSG_SIZE)

        except socket.timeout as e:
            err = e.args[0]
            if err == 'timed out':
                time.sleep(1)
                print(hex(id(proto)) + '...')
                continue
            else:
                print(e)
                proto.running = False

        except socket.error as e:
            # Something else happened, handle error, exit, etc.
            print(e)
            proto.running = False

        else:
            if len(msg) == 0:
                print('orderly shutdown on server end\n')
                proto.running = False
            else:
                proto.handle_msg(msg)

    proto.shutdown_proto()
```

The server outputs

```
orderly shutdown on server end
```

Client code

```
int CSocket::ConnectToHost(const char *hostName, unsigned int ipAddr, unsigned int portNum, bool doPoll)
{
  char * pMsg;
  //Create a Socket Descriptor
  if ((m_sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, doPoll ? IPPROTO_TCP : 0)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
  {
    mReportFacility.report(kReportError, "Ethernet (%u) socket: Error: Could not create Socket. ", getMachineID());
    return ERR_CREATESOCKET;
  }

  //Create sockaddr_in structure and fill up the data
  sockaddr_in dest; // the address of the destination computer
  dest.sin_family = AF_INET;
  dest.sin_port = htons(portNum); 
  dest.sin_addr.s_addr = (unsigned long)ipAddr;
  memset(&(dest.sin_zero), '\0', 8);  // zero the rest of the struct 

  unsigned long fpPolling = 1;

  if (doPoll)
  {
    int flags = fcntl(m_sockfd, F_GETFL, 0);
    fcntl(m_sockfd, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);
  }

  int retVal = 0;

  struct timeval tval;
  tval.tv_sec = 2;
  tval.tv_usec = 0;

  //Connect to the Server 
  int Cnkt = 0;
  Cnkt = connect(m_sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&dest, sizeof(dest));

  if (Cnkt < 0)
  {
    pMsg = ErrorMessage();

    fd_set rset, wset;

    FD_ZERO(&rset);
    FD_SET(m_sockfd, &rset);

    FD_ZERO(&wset);
    FD_SET(m_sockfd, &wset);

    if (doPoll)
    {
      retVal = select(m_sockfd + 1, &rset, &wset, NULL, &tval);
    }
    else
    {
      retVal = 1;
    }
    
    if ( retVal < 0 ) // error
    {
      mReportFacility.report(kReportError, "Ethernet (%u) socket: connect to host select failed %s. ", getMachineID(), pMsg);
    }
    else if ( retVal == 0 ) // time out
    {
      mReportFacility.report(kReportError, "Ethernet (%u) socket: connect timeout failed %s. ", getMachineID(), pMsg);
    }
    // else it may be success
    else
    {
      if( FD_ISSET(m_sockfd, &rset) || FD_ISSET(m_sockfd, &wset) )
      {
        
        int ferr;
        int len = sizeof (ferr);
        retVal = getsockopt(m_sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, (char*) &ferr, &len);

        if( retVal < 0  || (ferr != 0) )
        {
          pMsg = ErrorMessage();
          mReportFacility.report(kReportError, "Ethernet (%u) socket: connect to host getsocket failed %s. ", getMachineID(), pMsg);
        }
        else
        {
          Cnkt = 0;
        }
      }
      else
      {
        mReportFacility.report(kReportError, "Ethernet (%u) socket: connect failed %s. ", getMachineID(), pMsg);
      }
  }

  if (Cnkt != 0)
  {
    mReportFacility.report(kReportError, "Ethernet (%u) connect to host failed.", getMachineID());
    DisconnectFromHost();
  }

  return Cnkt;
}
```

Client output

```
Ethernet (0) socket: connect to host getsocket failed Operation now in progress.
error: got 111 from getsockopt(47)
Ethernet (0) connect to host failed.
```

For some reason the connection gets disconnected right away by the simulator because it gets `len(msg) == 0` from the `msg = proto.connection.recv(proto.MAX_MSG_SIZE)`.

**Why would the server close the connection immediately when the client is starting up but connect when client has been running?**

The client gets the ECONNREFUSED when attempting the connection on boot but doesn't once it's been running. The server is always running, just sitting there waiting for a connection from clients.

Thought timing was the issue and tried adding a sleep in the server and still get the disconnect.

I'm assuming it's a problem with the server simulator because it's the one issuing the TCP reset..

But I don't know why it does this when the client is starting up but not once the client has been running. It works perfectly after the client starts up. Maybe the client isn't fully ready by the time we attempt the connection? But not sure why that would cause the server to issue the TCP reset.

Anyone know what it could be?

Comment: so your actual question is 'why does proto.connection.recv return length 0 message?' What is proto.connection?

Comment: Can't speak to what `proto.connection` is, but in general any `recv()` operation is going to return 0 bytes when the peer has gracefully shutdown their own end of the connection. @RAZ_Muh_Taz, please provide a [mcve] showing your actual client code, and your server code that sets up the call to `recv_msgs()`

Comment: @pm100 proto.connection is a socket from when the server is do it's own sock.accept()

Comment: @RemyLebeau added the c++ client code.

Comment: Suggest you print out `ferr`. The `getsockopt(..., SO_ERROR...)` itself will not fail if the connect didn't succeed. That is, `getsockopt` will only fail if it's *unable to get the error status* for some reason. Otherwise, it will succeed *even if* it's retrieved an error on the queried connection. And since it doesn't fail, `errno` will not get set for that call. (I'm assuming `errno` is what `ErrorMessage()` is retrieving since it doesn't take an argument.) So you are likely just re-printing the error from the last failed system call (i.e. from the `connect`).

Comment: @GilHamilton the error code i get from ferr is 111